# How to insert, update and delete table records in nifi?

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

I am learning nifi processes and I have tried to implement a scenario in which we will insert, update and delete table records at the same time.

I have two tables in two different databases. source_table_2 in first database and target_table_2 in second database.
Following are the properties along with process names:

Properties of **QueryDatabaseTable**
[image]

Properties of **PutSQL**
[image]

Properties of **ConvertAvroToJSON**
[image]

Properties of **ConvertJSONToSQL**
[image]

Properties of Second **PutSQL** process
[image]

Properties of **PutDatabaseRecord**
[image]

The following is the complete diagram of the processes:

Nifi Insert and Update Process Diagram First Part
[image]

Nifi Insert and Update Process Diagram Last Part
[image]

Now after running all the processes, whenever I dump the record in the source_table_2 table in first database, the same record gets automatically dumped in target_table_2 in second database but whenever I try to update any record, it does not work. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

---

Sorry,let me explain.
Based on the [documentation of PutDatabaseRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/)

If the Statement Type is **UPDATE** or **UPSERT** and the property of update keys is not set then the update will happen based on the table's Primary Keys. If no Primary Key exists, in this case, the conversion to SQL will fail if Unmatched Column Behaviour is set to FAIL.
Therefore, it is better if you specify your table row identifier.
Update records Data Flow
[image: Update records Data Flow]

Here HashContent processor and DetectDuplicate in order to avoid any duplicate records **Just for validating**

Configuration of PutDatabaseRecord

[image: Configuration of PutDatabaseRecord]

The second way as shown in the following figure below
[image: figure]
The configuration of CONVERTJSONTOSQL processor
If the column names in the flow file are not equivalent to the column names in your database then you need to
set translate field name to false , otherwise true.
in update keys , I set two ids to show you that is applicable to have composite   key identifier

[image: Convert Data]
In PutSQL processor , you do not need to do anything except the connection and relations. If you write update query in sqlstatement property, you will overwrite the query that will be created by convert processor.

[image: update data]

I hope I clarified well.